# Convert a javascript timer function to use asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this javascript function, which uses a timer to call an ajax file every 2 seconds.
However, I see that this data is sent to the ajax file before the execution of previous data is complete. That is, it sends the whole list in about 10 seconds, while the data takes around 120 seconds to be processed.

**Is there a way, I can send the next data node, only when the previous has finished processing?**
`cb.call(this)` is being used to call a function, when this timer is finished,
while `querylimit` is a response variable, which exits the function if its true.

```
var i = 0;
var querylimit=false;
function refreshTimer(list,cb,i){
    if (!(i >= 0)) { i= 0; }
    setTimeout((function(chunk){
        i++;
        return function(){
            if (querylimit) { cb.call(this); }
            if(i <= list.length && !querylimit){
                refreshTimer(list,cb,i);
                refreshClients(chunk);
            }
            if(i == list.length+1) { cb.call(this); }
            if(i > list.length+1 || querylimit) { return null; }
        }
    }) (list[i]), 2000);
}
```

Regards
Nikhil Gupta

Comment: "if (!(i >= 0)){" --> ???? omg :) Anyway, don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. You want to chain function calls? So why do you use setTimeout? Just call the next when the first one ends.

Comment: when `i` has other values (I use `i` a lot, and hence..) is that a wrong thing to do?? :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically setup what I call a "cascade", which is a chain reaction of *window.setTimeout(...)* calls, rather than a single *window.setInterval(...)* call.

Instead of:

```
function requestAjaxData() {
    // prep ajax / call onAjaxDataReceived on success.
}
function onAjaxDataReceived() {
    // process data
}
window.setInterval(requestAjaxData, 2000);
```

I do:

```
function requestAjaxData() {
    // prep ajax / call onAjaxDataReceived on success.
}
function onAjaxDataReceived() {
    // process data

    // continue the cascade
    requestAjaxDataCascade();
}
function requestAjaxDataCascade() {
    window.setTimeout(requestAjaxData, 2000);
}
requestAjaxDataCascade();
```

Comment: can you please extend the example to provide how can I inject data into the above functions, i.e. lets say I have a array of arrays in json format, how can I make the `requestAjaxData` only send sub-arrays one at a time? I would really appreciate this. I was not aware about this particular thing, and hence, I am using Timer to increment the list-index (`i`) at the moment.